# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined( WHILE SORTING NODES ON EXPAND)

Tags: extjs4.1, treepanel

I want to the sort the tree node when it is expanded. I have been struggling to do this in extjs 4.1.0 with `itemexpand` or `beforeItemExpand` event using the following code. It works fine in ExtJS 4.2.1.

When I click on node to expand, I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined  at:  
     ns[i].viewRecordId = records[i].internalId
in  updateIndexes : function(startIndex, endIndex) method of Ext.view.AbstractView
class
```

Code:

```
var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    fields: ['displayName', 'type', 'value', 'stateSize', 'percentOfParent'],
    root: {
        "displayName": "state",
            "name": "state",
            "stateSize": 1.91,
            "percentOfParent": 100.0,
            "percentOfTotalstate": 100.0,
            "leaf": false,
            "cls": "highlight-new",
            "children": [{
            "displayName": "Component Tree",
                "name": "Tree",
                "stateSize": 0.25,
                "percentOfParent": 13.0,
                "percentOfstate": 13.0,
                "leaf": true,
                "cls": "highlight-new",
                "iconCls": "task",
        }, {
            "displayName": "crap",
                "name": "Tree",
                "stateSize": 0.25,
                "percentOfParent": 13.0,
                "percentOfstate": 13.0,
                "leaf": true,
                "cls": "highlight-new",
                "iconCls": "task",
        }]
    });

Ext.define('xyz.mytree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'State',
    alias: 'widget.state',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'displayName',
        width: 300
    }, {
        header: 'Type',
        dataIndex: 'type',
        width: 275
    }, {
        header: 'Value',
        dataIndex: 'value',
        align: 'left',
        width: 275
    }, {
        header: 'Size (KB)',
        dataIndex: 'stateSize',
        align: 'right',
        width: 95
    }, {
        header: '% Of Parent',
        dataIndex: 'percentOfParent',
        align: 'right',
        width: 95
    }],
    store: mystore,

    listeners: {

        itemExpand: function (node) {
            sortFunction = function (o1, o2) {
                if (o1.data.displayName < o2.data.displayName) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.data.displayName > o2.data.displayName) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            };

            if (!node.expanded) {
                node.sort(sortFunction, false, false);
                node.expanded = true;
            }
        }

    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

In 4.1, if the event used is itemExpand or beforeItemExpand, I receive the above error. But if I use afterItemExpand it works fine. in 4.2.1 it works fine on other events as well...

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there any alternative? Let me know if something is not clear abt the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while using `Ext.view.View`

So as suggested [here](https://architectslog.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/sencha-ext-js-4-and-cannot-read-property-internalid-of-undefined/)
I changed

```
itemSelector: 'div'
```

to

```
itemSelector: 'div#someId'
```

https://architectslog.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/sencha-ext-js-4-and-cannot-read-property-internalid-of-undefined/